# How to combine 2 select statements and output of two columns from one table?

Tags: sql-server

i'm newbie on Sqlserver
Here is my table.

```
 req
 61-01-0001
 61-02-0002
 61-03-0004
 61-04-0005
```

And this is my sql query.

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(req,4))as rq FROM tbl_inv_req  
UNION  
SELECT Substring(req,4,2) as rs  FROM tbl_inv_req
```

here The output

```
 rq
 0001
 0002
 0004
 0005
```

I want the output to look like.

```
 rq       rs
----     ----
 0001     01
 0002     02
 0004     03
 0005     04
```

pls tell me what i miss in my sql query. 
Thanks in advance for the help as usual.

Comment: No need if using union here because you want result in 2 columns. Try this 'SELECT 
    MAX(RIGHT(req,4))as rq,
    Substring(req,4,2) as rs 
FROM 
    tbl_inv_req '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a `UNION`. You can select as follows.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(req,4)as rq,
    Substring(req_id,4,2) as rs 
FROM 
    tbl_inv_req
```

`UNION` combines the results of two or more queries into a single result.

For comment:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(req,4) as rq,
    Substring(req_id,4,2) as rs 
FROM 
    tbl_inv_req 
WHERE
    RIGHT(req,4) = '0005' AND
    Substring(req_id,4,2) = '04'
```

Comment: sorry for bother you .but if i need to display only 

`rq      rs
0005  04` 

 what should i use?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
 MAX(RIGHT(req, 4)) AS rq,
 SUBSTRING(req_id, 4, 2) AS rs
FROM tbl_inv_req;
```

Comment: thank you for helping me. now i can go to  next step